# E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: null: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I did have this code working before now that I've added a new recipe with image from gallery all of the other images are messed up and not showing correct images etc. Any suggestions? I can add further files if need be but the database remains essentially unchanged. But something has caused the images not to load correctly

**Adapter**

```
public class RecipeCategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipeCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Category> categoryList;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private RecipeCategoryAdapter.ItemClickListener mClickListener;

// data is passed into the constructor
public RecipeCategoryAdapter(Context context, List<Category> data) {
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.categoryList = data;
}

// inflates the row layout from xml when needed
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_recipe, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

/**
 * Called by RecyclerView to display the data at the specified position. This method should
 * update the contents of the {@link ViewHolder#itemView} to reflect the item at the given
 * position.
 * <p>
 * Note that unlike {@link ListView}, RecyclerView will not call this method
 * again if the position of the item changes in the data set unless the item itself is
 * invalidated or the new position cannot be determined. For this reason, you should only
 * use the <code>position</code> parameter while acquiring the related data item inside
 * this method and should not keep a copy of it. If you need the position of an item later
 * on (e.g. in a click listener), use {@link ViewHolder#getAdapterPosition()} which will
 * have the updated adapter position.
 * <p>
 * Override {@link #onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, int, List)} instead if Adapter can
 * handle efficient partial bind.
 *
 * @param holder   The ViewHolder which should be updated to represent the contents of the
 *                 item at the given position in the data set.
 * @param position The position of the item within the adapter's data set.
 */
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (getItemCount() == 0) {
        holder.myTextView1.setText("No recipes Yet");
    } else {
        holder.myTextView1.setText(categoryList.get(position).getRecipe_name());
        holder.myTextView2.setText(categoryList.get(position).getCategory_name());
        String image2 = categoryList.get(position).getImage2();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image2);
        if (myBitmap != null)
            holder.imgImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        else
            holder.imgImage.setImageResource(categoryList.get(position).getImage());
    }
}

// total number of rows
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return categoryList.size();
}

// allows clicks events to be caught
void setClickListener(RecipeCategoryAdapter.ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
}


// parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);

}

// stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView myTextView1;
    TextView myTextView2;
    ImageView imgImage;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        myTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDay);
        myTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dayOfWeek);
        imgImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgImage);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Recipe.class);
                intent.putExtra("NAME", myTextView1.getText().toString());
                Log.d("myTextView1", myTextView1.getText().toString());
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Called when a view has been clicked.
     *
     * @param v The view that was clicked.
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

}

**Code used to save image to database**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int image = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        picturePath = cursor.getString(image);
        cursor.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is this about? What should your code do that it does not? Any errors?

Comment: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: null: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)  Thats the error

Comment: Even uninstalling app and reinstalling won't display the correct images that are saved in thr database as drawable.

Comment: And which statement causes that exception? And which file or directory is not found? Full path please.